# Redshift table insert with identity column getting table not found error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I have created table in redshift and inserted data as follows:

```
create table schema_name.employee (
surrogate_key bigint IDENTITY(1,1), 
first_name varchar(200), 
last_name varchar(200), 
phone_number varchar(200), 
creditcard_number bigint
)

insert into schema_name.employee(first_name,last_name,phone_number,creditcard_number)
values('gaurang', 'shah', '356-776-4456', 4716973408090483)
```

Above statements created redshift table and inserted data into table successfully(I tried in dbeaver by connecting to redshift host).

Same I am trying with glue script for inserting data into table as follows:

```
insert_query = """insert into schema_name.employee(first_name,last_name,phone_number,creditcard_number)
values('gaurang', 'shah', '356-776-4456', 4716973408090483)"""

spark.sql(insert_query).write \
  .format("com.amazonaws.redshift.spark") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("dbtable","schema_name.employee") \
  .option("user","user") \
  .option("password", "password") \
  .option("driver", driver) \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save()
```

I am getting error as table not found. Not sure what I am missing here. I am able read data from the table as follows and could able to see the data.
**Issue with writing data into table.**

```
query = "select * from schema_name.employee"
emp_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("query",query) \
  .option("user","user") \
  .option("password", "password") \
  .option("driver", rs_driver) \
  .load()
```

Here is the error details when I am trying insert data:

```
ame": "AnalysisException",
    "message": "Table not found: schema_name.employee; line 1 pos 12;\n'InsertIntoStatement 'UnresolvedRelation [schema_name, employee], [], false, [first_name, last_name, phone_number, creditcard_number], false, false\n+- LocalRelation [col1#147, col2#148, col3#149, col4#150L]\n",
    Table not found: schema_name.employee; line 1 pos 12;\n'InsertIntoStatement 'UnresolvedRelation [schema_name, employee], [], false, [first_name, last_name, phone_number, creditcard_number], false, false\n+- LocalRelation [col1#147, col2#148, col3#149, col4#150L]\n"
}
```

Table present in redshift but it is not able to recognize when we are trying to insert data through glue script.

Can someone provide some insight on how it works and what I am missing.

Thanks in advance,
Bob

Comment: Did you COMMIT the results of your first session?

Comment: Yes. Also I have created table manually. I could able to read this table but when I am trying to insert data, I am getting this issue

Comment: OK good.  Based on the error message I think that "schema_name.employee" is being sent as the table name, not as schema.table.  You could check this by setting search_path to include the schema and then just query the table by name only.